# How to optimize/streamline this unique/sort sequence?

Tags: matlab

I have a `table` where some (in fact, *most*) records appear multiple times.  I want to reorder the records so that all the multiple occurrences of a given record are contiguous, and I want to do this in a way that preserves "the order of first appearance."  I also want the indexes of the first occurrences of each unique record in the reordered table, so that I can quickly access each block of repeated records.

<sub>**NOTE:** in the example below, `tbl` refers to one of MATLAB's new (as of R2013b?) `table` objects, but the example will also work if `tbl` is defined simply as a vector of characters.  Just delete the `table(` and `)` from the definition of `tbl`.</sub>

Here's an example.  Suppose the original table is this:

```
>> tbl = table('CAABCB'.')  % example works also with tbl = 'CAABCB'.';
tbl = 
    Var1
    ____
    C   
    A   
    A   
    B   
    C   
    B
```

The desired reordered table is

```
    Var1
    ____
    C   
    C   
    A   
    A   
    B   
    B
```

...and the vector of first positions is `[1 3 5].'`.

(Note that desired reordered table above is *different* from what `sortrows(tbl)` would generate.  The difference lies in that the ordering of the desired table preserves the order of first occurrence, so `C` comes before `A` and `B`, etc. since, in the original table `tbl`, the first appearance of `C` occurs before the first appearances of `A` and `B`.)

Here's how I do this:

```
    [~, ~, group_id_col] = unique(tbl, 'stable');
    [sorted_group_id_col, sort_perm] = sort(group_id_col);
    reordered_tbl = tbl(sort_perm, :);
    [~, group_locs, ~] = unique(sorted_group_id_col, 'stable');
```

This produces the desired values for `reordered_tbl` and `group_locs`, but it does so by four *T* ≥ *O*(*N*) operations, where *N* is the number of rows in `tbl`.

Can it be done with fewer such operations using MATLAB built-ins?